# APA if more than three authors put et al

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I have a problem with the following.
I need the following citation style:

- if one author just show that author,
- if three authors, for first time show all three, but in subsequent citations show just the first one and *et al.*
- if more than three authors just show the first one then *et al.*

The following document works correctly to show the authors if more than three for first time and then subsequently shows the first author plus *et al.*

BUT the problem when there are more than four authors how to show just show the first author then *et al.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
  author = {Author, A.  and Buthor, B  and Cuthor, C and Duthor, D},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = 2013
}
@article{test2,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B and Cuthor, C and Duthor, D},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = 2012
}
@article{test3,
  author = {Author, A.  and Buthor, B  and Cuthor, C and Duthor, D and wael , mohamed and yafooz },
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = 2013
}
\end{filecontents}


\newcommand{\citelist}{}

\newcounter{currentcite}
\newcounter{currentcitetotal}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{
  \setcounter{currentcitetotal}{0}
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\addtocounter{currentcitetotal}{1}}
  \docsvlist{#1}
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{currentcite}{1}%
  \ifinlist{##1}{\citelist}
    {\citet{##1}}
    {\citet*{##1}\listadd{\citelist}{##1}}%
  \ifnumcomp{\value{currentcitetotal}}{>}{\value{currentcite}}
    {, }
    {}%
  }
  \docsvlist{#1}
}


\begin{document}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\mycite{test1,test2}
ffffffffffffffffff
\mycite{test1}
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
\mycite{test2}
ffffffffffffffffff\mycite{test3}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered switching to biblatex? You should be able to do what you want fairly easily in that case. (I'm not saying there isn't a bibtex solution - just I know biblatex pretty much gives you this sort of flexibility ready-made.)

Comment: You can't use the `plainnat` bibliography style and expect proper APA citation styles, which are quite convoluted. Either use the `biblatex-apa` style for `biblatex` or the actual `apacite` package for use with regular `bibtex`.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of your custom cite command?

Comment: @AlanMunn `\mycite` switches between the full author list the first time (i.e., `\citet*`) and the short author list (i.e., `\citet`).

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Ok, so then doing this with a package designed for it is a much better plan.